# pgsql - не получается портировать запрос для postgressql с if then в сортировке

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не получается изменить запрос с **mysql** на **pgsql**.

Ошибка конкретно в сортировке на условии:

```sql
    SELECT
    "modTransportPackage".*,
    "Provider"."name" AS "provider_name" 
FROM
    "modx_transport_packages" AS "modTransportPackage"
    LEFT JOIN "modx_transport_providers" "Provider" ON modTransportPackage.provider = Provider.ID 
WHERE
    (
        "modTransportPackage"."workspace" = 1 
        AND (
        SELECT
            "signature" 
        FROM
            "modx_transport_packages" AS "latestPackage" 
        WHERE
            "latestPackage"."package_name" = "modTransportPackage"."package_name" 
        ORDER BY
            "latestPackage"."version_major" DESC,
            "latestPackage"."version_minor" DESC,
            "latestPackage"."version_patch" DESC,
        IF
            ( "release" = '' OR "release" = 'ga' OR "release" = 'pl', 'z', IF ( "release" = 'dev', 'a', "release" ) ) DESC,
            "latestPackage"."release_index" DESC 
            LIMIT 1 
        ) = "modTransportPackage"."signature" 
    ) 
ORDER BY
    "modTransportPackage"."signature" ASC 
    LIMIT 20
```

Пробовал что-то по типу:

```
CASE 
            "release" WHEN '' 
            OR "release" WHEN 'ga' 
            OR "release" WHEN 'pl'
            THEN 'z'
            ELSE 
                CASE 
                    "release" WHEN 'dev' 
                    THEN 'a'
                    ELSE "release"
                END 
        END 
        DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` - это конструкция, которая используется в хранимых объектах (процедуры, триггеры и пр.).

Её аналогом, применяемым в выражениях запроса, является CASE. Т.е. вместо

```
IF ( "release" = '' OR "release" = 'ga' OR "release" = 'pl', 
     'z', 
     IF ( "release" = 'dev', 
          'a', 
          "release" 
        ) 
   ) DESC
```

следует использовать, например

```
CASE "release" WHEN ''    THEN 'z'
               WHEN 'ga'  THEN 'z'
               WHEN 'pl'  THEN 'z'
               WHEN 'dev' THEN 'a'
                          ELSE "release"
               END DESC
```

или

```
CASE WHEN "release" IN ('', 'ga', 'pl') THEN 'z'
     WHEN "release" = 'dev'             THEN 'a'
                                        ELSE "release"
     END DESC
```

Ваш вариант был близок к правильному. Надо было просто попристальнее посмотреть на синтаксис.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, выручили!!!